# How do you use npm fs?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm trying to make a Discord bot and I want to store a boolean value that will stay the same even when my bot restarts, I'm pretty sure I need fs to do this but I can't figure out how to use it, and I'm not successfully finding any documentation for it on github or npm...

So how would I go about storing a variable in a javascript file? (Or JSON if I need to)

Comment: `JSON.stringify` then `writeFile` somewhere, somewhen `readFile` and `JSON.parse`

Comment: why not use a database. What you're essentially asking is if you can create a file with a 0 or 1 in it, read from it, and write to it. Yes this is possible to do, but it's not the way you should store values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use for example LowDB [LowDB](https://github.com/typicode/lowdb). Super light-weight and allows easy read/write to a simple JSON file. All your storing is a simple boolean? Seems overkill to setup a full db engine.

Answer (score 0):

Hesitant to provide a solution here...You should NOT store values this way - you need to utilize a DB. Jonas' solution will work - but consider the DB route going forward.